# FB feed method does not work as it used to when sharing image and url

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to share image from FB app, using send dialog like I am doing for past few years.

```
var obj = {
  method: 'feed',
  link: 'https://www.facebook.com/pages/TESTPAGE?sk=app_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&app_data=share|10',
  caption: '',
  name: 'Title for share',
  description: 'description fort share',
  picture: IMG_URL
};
```

I have provide 2 screenshots 
when I click on share button inside of app [image]

what I keep getting on my profile wall.  [image]

Until few months ago, FB would show data from feed method, but now, feed is acting just like share method: it shares url, without image and labels I sent through feed dialog.

All I want is to share image from app, and url of that image should point to app url. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: I just stumbled your post since i have the exact same effect. I suppose there is a bug on Facebook. I will create bug report and send you link to support it.

Comment: Please login in and confirm the bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1656633411221093/

Comment: Facebook team confirmed that as a bug, so we just have to wait :). 
And thanks, I lost hours of trying to figure out what is wrong. I even made some workaround :)

Comment: @FlyLord do you have feed url security setting set to ON in settings (migrations tab)?

Comment: I don't have that tab for this app. I made this app few weeks ago

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue from yesterday. The issue only happens when you pass in the FB app link url to the Link option. The works fine with the images as long as the link url is not anything related to FB.

So the workaround I found was to get a shortened URL from google and passed it instead of the normal app link.

```
FB.ui({
    name: 'temp',
    method: 'feed',
    picture: '',
    link: '{shortened url}',
    caption: 'temp',
    description: 'temp',
    redirect_uri: 'any url'
    }, function(response){
});
```

Comment: Because this is a bug at facebook side :S

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to share image from FB app:

```
FB.ui(
    { 
        method: 'feed',
        display: 'popup',  // must be one of "popup", "dialog", "iframe", "touch", "async", "hidden", or "none"
        name: 'Title for share',
        description: 'Description for share',
        caption: 'www.facebook.com/YourFbPage/app_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        link: 'http://PathToYourDomain.com/Folder/',
        picture: 'http://PathToYourDomain.com/Folder/img/img-1200x627.jpg',

    },function(response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
        //  alert('Post was published.');
        } else {
       //   alert('Post was not published.');
        }
      }
    );
```

Best and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
FB.ui({
       method: 'share_open_graph',
       action_type: 'og.shares',
       action_properties: JSON.stringify({
            object : {
               'og:url': str_href,
               'og:title': 'title', //galleryItem.title,
               'og:description': 'desc', //galleryItem.description,
               'og:og:image:width': '2560',
               'og:image:height': '960',
               'og:image': str_picture //BASE_URL + '/images/works/galleries'
            }
        })
    });
```